# Google's autocomplete not activated by pasting with mouse

Tags: autocomplete, mouse, paste

The [Google autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete) doesn't seem to be activating by pasting content into a text input with the mouse. It works fine if involving the keyboard at all, but not with just mouse.

I did notice, however, that after you paste your content into the text input it will activate from almost any keypress (tested right arrow key, end key, space).

You can repro it here on their [autocomplete demo](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) site.

Is this a bug? or as designed? If it's as designed, how to apply workaround? 
I've got this as a workaround so far, but no simulated keypress events seem to work.

```
$('.txtLocation').bind("paste", function (e)
{
    $('.txtLocation').focus();
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.keyCode = 39; //39=Arrow Right
    $('.txtLocation').trigger(e);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems this impacts not only the context-menu Paste, but also that of Edit|Paste from the browser menu bar as well as the iOS paste functionality. I've opened a [bug with Google](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4671&q=apitype%3AJavascript3&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars). You may wish to "Star" that bug report to catch updates.

I found a workaround that, while a bit of a hack, seems to fix the problem. If you store the pasted value, switch focus on a different field, set the value in the Autocomplete field, and finally focus back on the Autocomplete field things work more or less as expected. Also, you have to do this in a `setTimeout()` callback - the delay time doesn't seem to matter at all, but if you just do this inline you won't see the expected results.

Here's a code sample of what I'm describing above:

```
$("#address_field").on("paste", googleMapsAutocompletePasteBugFix);

googleMapsAutocompletePasteBugFix = function() {
    return setTimeout(function() {
        var field, val;
        field = $("#address_field");
        val = field.val();
        $("#price").focus();
        field.val(val);
        return field.focus();
    }, 1);
};
```

The last `focus()` is optional, but the UI is a little less surprising than if you just skipped automatically to the next field.

Comment: Not bad. This fix works in Opera, FF, Chrome, and Safari, but not IE as it's still clearing it there. Wrapped it in .ready() and had to move the function above the reference to it so it would run without error. I suppose I'll leave this as it fixes all browsers but IE, but still not complete solution. Nice try though, +1 for effort. Any other ideas for IE?

Comment: I'll tell ya... freakin' IE man... And of course, if there's one browser where the users are more likely to use the right-click menu it's that one! Have you tried increasing the setTimeout delay to see if that changes things in IE?

Comment: Hm... Changing the timeout delay doesn't fix the IE issue. Played a while but no dice - starting to think the "solution" for IE is to unhide a DIV that contains a message advising IE users of the bug and suggesting they use CTRL+V to paste.

Comment: Rather than changing focus to another field and then back, you can trigger the blur event instead: http://jsfiddle.net/jdt0fajn/

Answer (score 0):

Following solution seems to work for me (existence of field ending with "address_2" is assumed). Tested on IE8, IE9, IE10, Chrome, FF and Safari

```
if document.addEventListener
      $(document).on("paste", "[name*=address_1]", @googleMapsAutocompletePasteBugFix)
      $(document).on("onpaste", "[name*=address_1]", @googleMapsAutocompletePasteBugFix)
    else
      for element in $("input[name*=address_1]")
        document.getElementById($(element).attr('id')).onpaste = @googleMapsAutocompletePasteBugFix

  googleMapsAutocompletePasteBugFix: (e) ->
    unless e
      e = window.event

    if e.srcElement
      target = e.srcElement
    else
      target = e.target

    field = $(target)
    fieldId = field.attr('id')
    focusSwitchFieldId = fieldId.replace(/(\d)$/, '2')

    setTimeout(->
      if window.chrome || /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent)
        val = field.val()
        $("##{focusSwitchFieldId}").focus()
        field.val(val)
        field.focus()
      else
        field = document.getElementById(fieldId)
        val = field.value
        document.getElementById(focusSwitchFieldId).focus()
        setTimeout(->
          field.value = val
          field.focus()
          field.focus()
        , 50)
    , 10)
```